# why label changed only once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my wpf app there are two pages, page1 an page2.

page1 looks something like:

```
public static int someVar;
public Page1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
.
.
.
// the user gives some value to "someVar"
    Page2 p2 = new Page2();
    void Next_btn(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
        {              
            p2.ChangLabel();
            this.NavigationService.GoForward();
        } else
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
    }
```

Page2 looks like:

```
public Page2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ChangeLable();
}
public void ChangeLable()
{
 MessageBox.Show("I'm here");

 if(Page1.someVar==1)
   myLabel.Content = "blabla";
 else
   myLabel.Content = "bbbbbb";
}
.
.
.
void Back_btn(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

let's say that the user done the following:

the user have been in `page1` and puts `someVar=1` and then goes to `page2`. therefore the function `ChangeLabel()` would change the lable to `blabla`.
after that he went back to page1 and changed `someVar=3` and then navigated again to page2 the problem in this scenario is that the label doesn't change to `bbbbb` even though the message box is showen

how to solve the following scenario?

I mean why in the second time the label does't changed to `bbbb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create two instances of `Page2`. You should pass `p2` to `NavigationService.Navigate` instead of creating a new one:

```
Page2 p2 = new Page2();
void Next_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
    {
        p2.ChangLabel();
        this.NavigationService.GoForward();
    }
    else
        NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
}
```